# PHP button send data to serial port (instead of CGI script

Tags: php, html, sockets, cgi

I have 2 working web pages that I am trying to merge into one. The first one is PHP, and on a button press, it opens a socket and sends a string of data to a device on my network.

The second web page has a similar function, but is not PHP. This page has buttons linked to CGI scripts, which are called and send data to the serial port.

I want to use the PHP web page, with some buttons functioning as they are now (opening a PHP socket and sending data to IP address),  but also have a few buttons that can send data to the serial port without using the CGI scripts or Java.

Here is the basic PHP page that works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<?php

// Checks to see if button pressed
if(isset($_POST['input'])) {

// Assigns value of button press to $input variable
$input=$_POST['input'];
//echo "$input<br />";

// Open the socket to the IP address
$sock = fsockopen('192.168.5.30:4660', NULL, $errno, $errstr);

// Send the value of the button press to the IP address
fwrite($sock, $input);

// Display the response from the socket on the webpage
echo fread($sock, 4096)."\n";

// Close the socket
fclose($sock); }

// If input is not set, then wait
else {
   //input is not set, do something about it, raise an error, throw an exception, or      whatever


}
?>


<head>
<style type="text/css">

 body {
font: 100% Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background: #666666;
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
color: #000000;
}

.newStyle1 {
float: left; 
}

.auto-style1 {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 20px;
}

</style>
<title>Audio Control</title>
</head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<body>

<form action="" method="post" >


<fieldset style="display:inline; border:none; padding:0px; margin:0px; vertical-align:top; class="newStyle1" style="height: 450px" >
  <legend align="center"; class="auto-style1">Backyard Audio</legend>
  <br/>
  <button name="input" style="height: 1.8em; width: 10em; font-size: 16px;" value="CL2I1O1T" type="submit">Computer</button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <button name="input" style="height: 1.8em; width: 10em; font-size: 16px;" value="CL2I2O1T" type="submit">Tuner</button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <button name="input" style="height: 1.8em; width: 10em; font-size: 16px;" value="CL2I3O1T" type="submit">Send serial data 1</button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <button name="input" style="height: 1.8em; width: 10em; font-size: 16px;" value="CL2I4O1T" type="submit">Send serial data 2</button>
      <br />
      <br />


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the basic CGI script that I am running:

```
#!/bin/sh -ax

#Send out the serial command in Hex code

 echo -e "OF1/r" > /dev/ttyACM0


#Redirect the browser back to the index page

 echo "Content-type: text/html"
 echo ""
 echo "<html><head><title>Audio Control</title>"
 echo "</head><body>"
 echo "<script type="text/javascript"><!--"
 echo "setTimeout('Redirect()',0);"
 echo " function Redirect(){  location.href = '../index.html';}"
PHP echo " --></script></body></html>"
```

The function I am interested in integrating into the PHP web page buttons is the echo -e "OF1/r" > /dev/ttyACM0. This command sends "OF1/r" to the serial port.

Thanks!

Comment: Haven't tried this, but will `$h=fopen("/dev/ttyACMO","w"); fwrite($h,"OF1/r"); fclose($h);` do what you need?

Comment: Ok, noob question... where do I put that in my code for this particular button?

Comment: In your existing code you're just sending the button value to some IP socket. You'd need to look at the button value first: `if ($input =="CL2I3O1T") { //send serial data } else { //do something else }`.